# x25519 curve key generation and authentication with OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl, elliptic-curve

I am using OpenSSL in C to write a client and a server which will have to authenticate their keys to each other. I want to use x25519 curve for key exchange, and the key exchange needs to be authenticated.

I know that the EVP interface provides such functionality but I cannot find any example somewhere (with some level of verbosity).

How do I perform x25519 curve key generation and authentication with OpenSSL; and how do I perform the exchange? Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Comment: x25519 is used for key exchange not authentication. To do authentication you will need to use something else as well. So what are you actually trying to do: key exchange; authentication; or key exchange *and* authentication?

Comment: I am writing a client and a server which will use ephemeral keys with the x25519 curve. The client or server should generate a shared secret so that when one of the two parties sends a payload the other should authenticate the sender's identity. Am I getting something wrong on how this stuff works?

Comment: The two concepts of key exchange (i.e. generating a shared secret) and authentication are entirely separate. X25519 is specifically concerned with the generation of a shared secret. Each party generates a public and a private value. They exchange public values and then using their own private value and the public value from the peer each of them can generate a shared secret than an eavesdropper will be unable to calculate. This doesn't in any way provide authentication which enables one party to verify the identity of the other party.

Comment: i.e. with X25519 alone you know you can communicate securely with *someone* but not who that someone is. To authenticate them you need to combine that with something like ECDSA, RSA or Ed25519 (although the latter mechanism isn't currently supported in OpenSSL - it will be in the next version)

Comment: If I understood you correctly, after the shared secret is derived then both parties can use that to communicate BUT the message exchange is not secured (?). ECDSA, RSA or Ed25519 encrypts the message to provide forward secrecy.

Comment: Kind of. The message exchange itself is not secured. So the client doesn't know whether it is talking to the server it thinks it is (instead of, for example some malicious third party pretending to be the server). Vice versa for the server. ECDSA/RSA/Ed25519 does not encrypt the key exchange - it adds a digital signature to it. In fact often it will sign more than just the key exchange, e.g. other meta-data in the protocol messages used during the key exchange. By verifying the signature each peer can confirm that they are communicating with who they think they are.

Comment: You should consider whether SSL/TLS actually meets your needs. All of this is built into the protocol in a well defined and secure way. Doing it yourself is not recommended, as it is difficult to get right.